# How to elegantly create a blank line between paragraphs

Tags: paragraphs, line-spacing

I use

```
\\ \  \\
```

( The middle part is \ followed by a space.)

to create a blank line between paragraphs because I could not find an easier way.

Can you help me finding a more easy ( elegant ) way to do this?

Comment: If you want it for every paragraph separation, use `\parskip=1ex` in the preamble, with whatever dimension is desired.  For one-time use, use `\vspace{1ex}` at the beginning of the paragraph requiring separation.

Comment: Thank you, I will try these.

Comment: \parskip=1ex works quite differently. The spacing between the lines becomes less.

Comment: never use `\\ ` to add an end of paragraph space it does not genererate vertical space but rather a white line of "text" as such the line for example will not be dropped at the start of a page so you will get large gaps at tops of pages.  Use `\usepackage{parskip}`to use a style using vertical space rather than indent to mark paragraphs.

Comment: So \usepackage{parskip} will suffice?

Comment: well 1ex is the height of an x so clearly less than `\baselineskip`which is the inter-line space, you could use `\vspace{\baselineskip}`but you should almost never need to use such explicit spacing in a document. The inter-paragraph space should be specified as part of the document layout, not on every paragraph.

Comment: Try `\advance\parskip by 1ex`.  Whatever the default is, this will be bigger.  See also `\smallskip`, `\medskip` and `\bigskip`.

Comment: I got the document built as I wanted it without the ugly "\\ \ \\" but I am not entirely sure why or how it works. But that is my bad: I have some reading to do. Thank you all for the kind helpful comments. They really helped me.